# Simplifying a polynomial equation (undergraduate algebra)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, elementary-functions

$$\frac{ab^2}{x^2} = \frac{c (P-Q) x^3}{P}$$

I've got the expression above and should express it in terms of $x$, knowing that $a, b, c$ and $Q$ are constants and $P = \sqrt{Q^2 + \frac{x^2}{4}}$

---

Also, we know that $Q >> x$, so I decided to use the first terms of the Taylor expansion for $P$, so $$P \approx Q(1+\frac{x^2}{8Q^2})$$

By doing so, we get $ab^2(Q + \frac{x^2}{8Q}) = c(\frac{x^2}{8Q})x^5$

In order to solve for $x$, I would have to solve this $7^{th}$ degree equation. So, assuming that $x^2 \approx 2x$, we get a $5^{th}$ degree equation

$ab^2(Q + \frac{x}{4Q}) = c(\frac{x}{4Q})x^5$ wich looks less ugly, but I still can't solve it.

Do you guys have any ideas?

I thank you in advance for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

multiplying both sides by $x^2$ we get
$$ab^2=\frac{c(P-Q)x^5}{P}$$ and then multiply by $$\frac{P}{c(P-Q)}$$ you will get
$$\frac{ab^2P}{c(P-Q)}=x^5$$
$$x=\sqrt[5]{\frac{ab^2P}{c\left(P-\sqrt{D^2-\frac{x^2}{4}}\right)}}$$
and now you will Need a numerical method!
you can not solve it by an explicit formula, it is an higher order polynomial
with your correction you will get
$$ab^2(4Q^2+x)=cx^6$$ and for this equation you will also Need a numerical method!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to express it in terms of $D$.

Comment: yes thats true, i will correct it!

Comment: I am sorry, there is a typo in my original question. The variable $D$ does not exist, it is just $P = \sqrt{Q^2 + \frac{x^2}{4}}$. Thus, you don't need to express it in terms of $P$, but solve for $x$ instead. The question is already fixed. Anyway, thank you for your attention!

Comment: Ok, thanks again! I was expecting to find another correction that we could apply to the expression in order to solve it for x _without any numerical method._ So, if you know any approximation that could be applied, I would be glad to know it!